# Steps in list question, Python beginner

Tags: python

The following code include the last number.

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> numbers[::3]
[1, 4, 7, 10]
```

Why does not includet the last number 2, like 10, 8, 6, 4, 2?

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> numbers[:1:-2]
[10, 8, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the slice operator is simply non-inclusive of the second argument. In other-words, your `1` should be a `0`:

```
>>> numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> numbers[:1:-2]
[10, 8, 6, 4]
>>> numbers[:0:-2]
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

Hope that helps :)

For further info, see Note 5 [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange).

Comment: That works too, of course, but my point was to show that the argument `1` was the issue. Plus, making general statements like "Python will use 0 where arguments are lacking" are likely to be troublesome.

Answer (score 2):

:: is walking over the list with N steps. So it's 1, then it goes to 4, etc. If you want to step with 2 backwards, you want [::-2]

Answer (score 2):

Python is pretty consistent in following the pattern of sequence ranges being lower inclusive, upper exclusive.  That is, if you say range(1,5) --> [1,2,3,4].  The lower index is included and the upper is excluded.  This helps a lot with various kinds of off-by-one and fencepost errors.  See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) for a brief explanation of these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Because the slice excludes the second number from the range. `a[1:4]` fetches elements 1, 2 and 3. Likewise, `a[10:6:-1]` fetches elements 10, 9, 8 and 7, but not 6.

Comment: numbers[10:6:-1] outputs 10, 9, 8 not 7.

Comment: I was referring to the elements in positions 10 through 7 in some arbitrary array, `a`.